# Installation of azure toolkit for eclipse is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

I was following this link  [to install the plugin for azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse) in eclipse, but azure tool kit is not showing in available software's.
Please see the screenshot below 
[image: ![enter image description here]
I have checked my proxy settings. Everything seems to be correct. I have also tried to access the URL [http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse) from browser, but its giving me the message **You do not have permission to view this directory or page**. Then I tried [eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse). That is also not working.I found below errors in eclipse error log

```
 The following solutions are not available: Azure Toolkit for Eclipse 3.0.3 (id=com.microsoft.azuretools.sdk.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.applicationinsights.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.azuretools.hdinsight.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.azuretools.core.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.sqljdbc4.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.azuretools.docker.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.azuretools.webapp.feature.feature.group, com.microsoft.azuretools.azureexplorer.feature.feature.group, site=http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse)
```

Can anyone please tell why the toolkit is not listing over the available software's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on error when you visited marketplace it seems you are using an older version of Eclipse. Azure toolkit is available for Mars or later versions of Eclipse which be required in the section [`Prerequisites`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-toolkit-for-eclipse-installation#prerequisites) and as the figure below from [here](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/azure-toolkit-eclipse).

[image]

So please first update your Eclipse, then install Azure Toolkit plugin via Eclipse Marketplace.